# Does the STL set equality operator check size first?

Tags: c++, stl, comparator, performance

When I'm using the == or != operator to compare two sets, does that operator actually compare the size of the two sets first?  I'm wondering if I need to manually compare the two sizes first to make it more efficient, or if I would actually be making it less efficient.  I know the equality and inequality operators will check size, I just don't know if it will do so first.

```
bool checkEqualTo( const set<int> & set1, const set<int> & set2 )
{
    // Should I include comparison of sizes first?
    if ( set1.size() != set2.size() )
    {
       return false;
    }
    if ( set1 != set2 )
    { 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's not needed.  If they're different sizes, they are not logically equivalent.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I tried to make it clear that unequal sizes will not be equal, I'm speaking from efficiency standpoint.  `I know the equality and inequality operators will check size, I just don't know if it will do so first.`

Comment: Exercise for the reader/writer: rewrite your function (with or without the size check) to only one line without using the ternary operator.

Comment: @Chance: Don't worry about it.  Trust the implementers, they tend to be better at such things than you are.  If it's faster, they probably did it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's the first thing that's checked — from the C++11 standard, §23.2.1 table 96 (Container requirements):

> **Expression:**
>
> `a == b` (where `a` and `b` denote values of type `X` and `X` denotes a container class containing objects of type `T`)
>
> **Operational semantics:**
>
> ```
>    distance(a.begin(), a.end()) == distance(b.begin(), b.end()) &&
>      equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin())
> ```

Comment: I wonder if that is still the case with the c++20 `auto operator<=>() = default` implicitly generated `operator==` overloading?

Comment: @MaxPower : The wording has changed, but the net effect is the same. [See here](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.gen.reqmts#container.reqmts) for updated requirements wording (currently passages 36-43), and keep in mind that just because it _can_ be implicitly generated does not imply that it _must_ be.